# Arduino with atmel tools

Tags: arduino, avr, atmel, programmer

Hi I've done some dev using AVR's.

I'd really like to use the arduino but continue using atmel tools.

Is this straightforward?

Is there a converter that I can use my 910 programmer with? I think it's a 10 pin connector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can.  All the schematics for the AVR910 programmer that I have found show it with a 6 pin interface.

[10 Pin to 6 Pin Converter](http://microcontrollershop.com/product%5Finfo.php?products%5Fid=1918)

A converter ought to do it.  Some programmers come with both interfaces, for instance the Adafruit Attiny USB programmer.  Loooking at its schematic, I can see that the 10 pin programmer has the same connections on it as the 6 pin, just a few not connected pins.  I assume that the 10 pin connectors pinout is standardised.  You of course could convert it yourself or build a similar converter as above without too much difficulty.